# Javascript; Browser history; Is there cross-browser way to read previous page url( history.go(-1) ), and second last page ( history.go(-2) )?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I need to dynamically get and process url's of previous two pages. Tried to do something like this but without luck(used Chrome, but I need solution for all browsers):

```
console.log(window.history.entries[window.history.index - 2]);
```

The only object that I can successfully get is "history.lenght".

This gives "undefined" multiple times too:

```
for (var i = window.history.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(window.history[i]);
}
```

**update:** I'm adding [Back] button and there is popup on server, that breaks my code. If popup appeared, I call history.go(-2). I noticed that it always appears in Chrome and Opera, and created workaround. But it is bad solution and I'm not sure it covers all situations, that's why I need to compare previous urls

```
if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") > -1 || navigator.userAgent.search("OPR") > -1) {
    // insert conditional Chrome code here
    console.log("Go Back button: Chrome or Opera detected, go two pages back.");
    history.go(-2);
    return false;
} else {
    console.log("Go Back button: Browser is not Chrome, go one page back.");
    history.go(-1);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to spy on my browsing history?

Comment: There is no javascript api to do that.  This would obviously not be good because the browser could not protect user's privacy.

Comment: Very funny).. I'm creating [Back] button for SharePoint online platform. And there is sometimes popup, that breaks my history.go(-1). I cannot prevent this popup and search a way to check if I need to call history.go(-1) or (-2). Believe me, I need Your browsing history same, as rabbit needs the moon..

Comment: @GennadyG that looks relevant information to be in the question and not in the coments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this on all the pages of your website..

```
localStorage.setItem('2PagesAgo', localStorage.getItem('lastPage'));
localStorage.setItem('lastPage', localStorage.getItem('thisPage'));
localStorage.setItem('thisPage', location.href);
```

Then to get the last and previous pages just do..

```
var lastPage = localStorage.getItem('lastPage');
var 2PagesAgo = localStorage.getItem('2PagesAgo');
```

This will allow you to track the last 2 pages a user visits on *your site*. Any browsing the user did outside of your site is none of your business. :)

Comment: Thank You @Occam's Razor! As I've understand there is no easy way to do it, buit Youк idea is cool! I'll wait till tomorrow and mark Your idea as answer.